# How to convert Arduino GSR values to microsiemens?

Tags: arduino-uno

In my project Arduino provides value range between 0-1024. I need to convert this serial value to a standard µSiemens value to measure emotional stress.

Can anybody point me to an answer that would give an appropriate equation for the conversion?

Comment: You understand that the ADC measures voltage, right?

Answer (score 1):

A Siemens (aka a Mho) is a unit of conductance, the inverse of resistance.

You have a measure of the voltage (A/D value) between the pads so you can find voltage. You'll also need to know the current between the pads.
Convert your A/D reading into voltage and use that and the current to find resistance (using Ohm's law), and the reciprocal of the resistance is in Siemens. 1 Siemens == 1,000,000 uSiemens.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siemens_(unit)